# Server, client - unsure how to implement functionality "If names are repeated a user is prompted to enter another"

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on a chatroom project with client - server functionality.

The last finishing touches is when a username is entered twice on the login screen it recognises the fact that is has already been entered twice and displays an error.

I've been working on this for a while and cannot seem to do it.

Steps to reproduce error:

1. Start server
2. Open client program
3. Enter a user name on login screen
4. Click enter and go to chatroom window
5. Start a new client window
6. Enter a user name of the same name on login screen
7. Click enter
8. Doesn't recognise that it is a duplicate user name and goes ahead and displays chatroom window anyways

Steps tried to try to resolve problem:

1. Tried to make a context class to pass objects between controllers before realising that this is a multi-threaded project
2. Put a getter for the user name list off the ChatClient class to access in the LoginController but cannot be accessed for some reason
3. Changed around the LoginController to implement Runnable and to store the threads to try and store username list but to no success

GitHub link: https://github.com/Runite618/ChatRoomVers2

Thanks for any replies.

Kind regards,

Matthew.

Comment: This means the server should know which users are currently logged in and if there is a login attempt for a user name that is already logged in that's an error. Basically this would mean the client tries a login but the server responds with an apropriate message.

Comment: Server knows it all in a usernames list, however, the LoginController is in a different project and I am not sure how to pass the arraylist of usernames from the server project to that controller without introducing sockets into the LoginController.

Comment: No, you don't send all the users to the client but let the client try to login and the server respond. It's much like a failed login attempt: you send the credentials to the server which then checks them and if they're not correct (e.g. wrong password) it sends some error code. In your case you just send a different error code.